# com.auth0.jwk.NetworkException: Cannot obtain jwks from url- caused by - Caused by: java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: docker, connection-refused

there is container running

docker-compose.yml:

```
keycloak:
     build: config
     image: docker.clear2pay.com/c2p-base/keycloak:8.0.2
     ports:
         - "9090:8443"
     environment:
           DB_VENDOR: h2
           KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
           KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password 
      networks:
           - custom_network
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.clear2pay.com/c2p-base/keycloak:8.0.2
EXPOSE 8443
```

https connection is refused to this container from another container in the same network (`custom_network`)

https://<container-name>:9090/auth/realms/paasv2sso/protocol/openid-connect/certs

Logs:

```
paas_mi_artifacts_1  | ***com.auth0.jwk.NetworkException: Cannot obtain jwks from url https://ci_keycloak_1:9090/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/certs***
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider.getJwks(UrlJwkProvider.java:139)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider.getAll(UrlJwkProvider.java:145)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider.get(UrlJwkProvider.java:163)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at com.fisglobal.paas.oauth.OAuthTokenVerifier.mediate(OAuthTokenVerifier.java:36)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.updateInstancePropertiesAndMediate(ClassMediator.java:178)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:97)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.api.Resource.process(Resource.java:342)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:463)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcess(AbstractApiHandler.java:93)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:71)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:84)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:70)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:101)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:375)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:182)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  | ***Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)***
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
paas_mi_artifacts_1  |  at
```

Comment: If you're connecting from one container to another, and the process in the server container is listening on port 8443, then the client should connect to that port.  `ports:` aren't considered (or required).